# Using association in @Embedded entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with doctrine embeddables and using associations in it. When i add `@ManyToOne` to embedded entity doctrine don't create `address_city` column in user table, however `address_street` column is created. I seams bit strange because there is no error, city is silently ommited.

Code look like this:

```
/** @Entity */
class User
{
    /** @Embedded(class = "Address") */
    private $address;
}

/** @Embeddable */
class Address
{
    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    private $street;

    /** @ManyToOne(targetEntity = "City") */
    private $city;
}

/** @Entity */
class City
{
    /** @Column(type = "string") */
    private $name;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

State for 2015.01.11:

This case is currently not supported in doctrine. It's now described in doctrine issue tracker [here](http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-3480)

Here is the explanation:

> We don't support associations from embeddables right now...
>
> It will probably not implemented for now, as embeddables (in our vision) are fitting the use-case of ValueObjects. ValueObjects are (usually) supposed to be containing serializable data, and an entity reference is not serializable data.

Comment: I believe this is just an excuse since the feature is really important and not having that makes the whole embeddables thingy incomplete. I am really disappointed with that.

Comment: Embeddable asstiations wouldn't be implemented ever: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/issues/4291 :-(